# Counting one field in sql with join

Tags: mysql

I have a table, named rendeles_termekek.(In english, ordered_products)

I would like to count, that each product how many times was ordered.

With the SQL below, I get 4 as ennyi. I upload a picture, and I wrote the correct number to each rows.

[image]

```
SELECT DISTINCT

                    rendeles_termekek.termek_id,
                    termek.termek_id, 
                    termek.termek_nev,

                    ( SELECT COUNT(rendeles_termekek.termek_id) FROM rendeles_termekek ) AS ennyi

                FROM rendeles_termekek

                LEFT JOIN termek ON rendeles_termekek.termek_id = termek.termek_id

                ORDER BY termek.termek_nev ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
**r1** is the alias of your table rendeles_termekek so you have to access those columns through alias name "r1" like I did in below query. try below

SELECT DISTINCT
                r1.termek_id,
                termek.termek_id, 
                termek.termek_nev,
                ( SELECT COUNT(r.termek_id) FROM rendeles_termekek r where r.termek_id = r1.termek_id ) AS ennyi
            FROM rendeles_termekek r1
            LEFT JOIN termek ON r1.termek_id = termek.termek_id
            ORDER BY termek.termek_nev ASC
```

Comment: "Unknown column 'r1.rendeles_termekek.termek_id' in 'field list'. "

Whats going on here? :D

Comment: Sorry.. It was my bad.. I misunderstood your table name. I have updated the query again. try to execute now

Comment: Now its okay. Thank you very! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have only four rows in your table "rendeles_termekek".

I have updated your query. try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
                rendeles_termekek.termek_id,
                termek.termek_id, 
                termek.termek_nev,
                ( SELECT COUNT(rendeles_termekek.termek_id) FROM rendeles_termekek r where r.termek_id = r1.termek_id ) AS ennyi
            FROM rendeles_termekek r1
            LEFT JOIN termek ON rendeles_termekek.termek_id = termek.termek_id
            ORDER BY termek.termek_nev ASC
```

Note that I have changed the sub-query and added a where condition in it

```
   `( SELECT COUNT(rendeles_termekek.termek_id) FROM rendeles_termekek r where r.termek_id = r1.termek_id ) AS ennyi`
```

Comment: Hello! I get this error: Unknown column 'rendeles_termekek.termek_id' in 'field list'